Finding a combinatorial specification for binary words
So I need to find a combinatorial specification for the set $\mathcal{W}_{odd}$ of all binary words where each non-empty block of $0$s has odd length, and I want to know if I did it right. I'm new to this type of counting.
Consider the word $1101110001 \in \mathcal{W}_{odd+0}$. If we cut this word after every block of $0$s and before every $10$, we get $(1,10,11,1000,1)$. Similarly, the word $0001100011110 \in \mathcal{W}_{odd+0}$ becomes $(000,1,1000,111,10,\epsilon)$. From this, we can see that the first block of any word is either empty, a sequence of $1$s, or an odd sequence of $0$s. A middle block is either a sequence of $1$s or a single $1$ followed by an odd number of $0$s, and the last block is either empty or a sequence of $1$s.
Thus $\mathcal{W}_{odd+0}=(\epsilon+1^*+0(00)^*)(1^*+10(00)^*)^*(\epsilon + 1^*)$. Is this right? My main struggle is I never know how to properly slice up a word to suit the given problem.

Your regular expression is correct.
Here is a simpler method. Break the string into blocks such that every block ends with a $1$, and has a single $1$. The only exception is that the very last block might consist of only zeroes. We see that the string is a sequence of blocks, where each block consists of either (i) a single $1$, or (ii) an odd number of zeroes followed by a single $1$, and optionally afterwards there might be a single block consisting only of an odd number of zeroes. Translating this English description into a regular expression,
$$
\mathcal W_{\text{odd}}=(1+0(00)^*1)^*(\epsilon +0(00)^*).
$$
The above expression is unambiguous, whereas your expression is ambiguous (in that it can generate the same string in multiple ways).
